Can’t get package that provides /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
I'm trying to migrate my Centos 8 Server to Rocky Linux. Im using the Migrate script but im getting this error:
[root@domain migrate2rocky]# ./migrate2rocky.sh -r
migrate2rocky - Begin logging at Mon 24 Jun 2024 02:51:09 PM -04.


Removing dnf cache
Preparing to migrate CentOS Stream 8 to Rocky Linux 8.

Determining repository names for CentOS Stream 8.Importing GPG key 0x210976F2:
 Userid     : "Package Manager (Package Signing Key) <packages@pgadmin.org>"
 Fingerprint: E869 7E2E EF76 C02D 3A63 3277 8881 B2A8 2109 76F2
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/PGADMIN_PKG_KEY
.....

Found the following repositories which map from CentOS Stream 8 to Rocky Linux 8:
CentOS Stream 8  Rocky Linux 8
AppStream        appstream
BaseOS           baseos
extras           extras

Getting system package names for CentOS Stream 8.^[[A^[[B.......Error: No Matches found

Can't get package that provides /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo.

An error occurred while we were attempting to convert your system to Rocky Linux. Your system may be unstable. Script will now exit to prevent possible damage.

 A log of this installation can be found at /var/log/migrate2rocky.log

This is my repo file:
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the #mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the 
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#

[BaseOS]
name=CentOS Stream $releasever - BaseOS
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8-stream&arch=$basearch&repo=BaseOS&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/8-stream/BaseOS/$basearch/os/
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

[AppStream]
name=CentOS Stream $releasever - AppStream
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8-stream&arch=$basearch&repo=AppStream&infra=$infra
#mirrorlist=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/repodata/i
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

[extras]
name=CentOS Stream $releasever - Extras
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/centos/8/extras/x86_64/os/
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8-stream&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/8-stream/extras/$basearch/os/
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/extras/x86_64/os/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

#[PowerTools]
#name=CentOS Stream $releasever - PowerTools
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8-stream&arch=$basearch&repo=PowerTools&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/8-stream/PowerTools/$basearch/os/
#gpgcheck=1
#enabled=0
#gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

#[centosplus]
#name=CentOS Stream $releasever - Plus
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8-stream&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/8-stream/centosplus/$basearch/os/
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/PowerTools/x86_64/os/
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/centosplus/x86_64/os/
#gpgcheck=1
#enabled=0
#gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

#[fasttrack]
#name=CentOS Stream $releasever - fasttrack
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8-stream&arch=$basearch&repo=fasttrack&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/8-stream/fasttrack/$basearch/os/
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/fasttrack/
#gpgcheck=1
#enabled=0
#gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

Thank you for any help.

rpm -qif /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo   and figure out what happened to this box such that repo file is not owned by a package.  The authors of migrate2rocky.sh do not support using it with customization to the repo file.
Your repo has vault uncommented. Vault is old insecure builds that should be avoided if possible, instead using the regular update repos. In addition to this challenge, migrate2rocky.sh does not deal well with vault enabled or other customizations.
Read the script for the bit around dealing with  repos.d on Stream.  Script does some normally suspect things, namely rpm -e --justdb --nodeps and dnf --setopt=protected_packages=    I assume  these are it editing repo files, prior swapping in the new Rocky release packages with equivalent repo files. Tricky operation given these are the package manager itself, and normally the dependencies do not allow these to be removed.
After backing up this host, consider installing the CentOS Stream repo file, such as   dnf install /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo  Then maybe the script can proceed.
As an alternative, be prepared to do a clean install of Rocky. When customization and data restore is automated, this will not take long. Especially compared to fighting the package manager to accomplish this upgrade.

I am not familiar with data restoration automation and I have some services running such as: Postfix, Apache, Postgresql. Programming languages ​​such as Python, PHP and others. It would be a lot of effort to install and configure everything again

If you are not prepared to do clean install and backup restores, you are not ready to upgrade a distro by any method. Especially when the method is something like this script, which disables safety measures to switch distro. Consider getting training or hiring someone for help.
